# Adding JavaScript type hints for VSCode/Monaco Intellisence

Tags: javascript, intellisense, visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

Is there a way to hint to VSCode/Monaco's intellisense the types of variables.

I have some code like this

```
var loc = window.location;
var gl = context1.getContext("webgl");
var ctx = context2.getContext("2d");
```

I see that VSCode knows that `loc` is a `URL`

[image: vscode knows loc]

But it doesn't know what `gl` is

[image: vscode does not know gl]

Nor does it know what `ctx` is

[image: vscode does not know ctx]

Which makes sense, having a function return different types based on its input is a somewhat unusual case.

But it does have type data for `WebGLRenderingContext`

[image: vscode knows webglrenderingcontext]

and it knows `CanvasRenderingContext2D`

[image: vscode knows canvasrenderingcontext2d]

Is there a way to for me to tell vscode/monaco that `gl` is an instance of `WebGLRenderingContext` and that `ctx` is an instance of `CanvasRenderingContext2D` without having to switch to typescript? Maybe by adding some kind of comment?

I need the solution to work in [monaco](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) (which at least in my tests shows all the same completions) because this is for a WebGL tutorial site, not actually for VSCode but I'm hoping the solution is the same.

Comment: JSDoc works in Monaco since version 0.90. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45181853/2102158.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## Update: As of 0.9.0 of Monaco these type annotations now work

---

Is see that [JSDoc style type annotations](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html) work in VSCode though they don't appear to work in Monaco.

```
var loc = window.location;

/** @type {WebGLRenderingContext} */
var gl = context1.getContext("webgl");    

/** @type {CanvasRenderingContext2D} */
var ctx = context2.getContext("2d");
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This technique doesn't appear to work for imported types.  e.g., `var Foo = require("foo"); /** @type {Foo} */ var foo;`  In this example, `Foo` is a type that VSCode recognizes and has full intellisense on.  If instead you do `var Foo = require("foo"); var foo = new Foo();` everything works.  Any pro-tips to make this work correctly with imported types?

Comment: @MicahZoltu I had a similar issue annotating types from the Express library.  I found how to make this work and posted an additional answer on this question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48752318/1359579

Comment: Important note: it *only* works if you use `/** */` comments. `/* */` and `//` comments have no effect annoyingly.

Answer (score 6):

As Micah pointed out in a comment on the accepted answer, there can still be issues with external modules.  Simply doing a require of the module will already enable jsdoc type annotations to work if the library defines a global object from which you can reference the types.  Otherwise, you can mimic this by importing everything and mapping it to your own name.

```
import * as Foo from 'foo'

/** @type {Foo.Foo} */
var foo;
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8237#issuecomment-213047062

Comment: It also works with function parameters ```const foo = (/** @type {Foo.Bar} */bar) => {...};```

Answer (score -2):

If you are willing to use Typescript, you can do this:

`var gl : WebGLRenderingContext;`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm using it on a site that's teaching stuff with JS not TS 

Comment: @gman Well typescript is pretty similar to javascript. much of it is very similar to javascript, very easy to convert over

Comment: @kinger6621 Nope, it's no easy: once that you are in TypeScript everything is "typed", and you must do follow with that.