# How to create a parameter type hint?

Tags: monaco-editor, react-monaco-editor

I want to do this:

```
function onMyEvent(event)
{
    event.someProperty
}
```

This question is the same as [Provide type hints to monaco editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037243/provide-type-hints-to-monaco-editor), but answers are not what i looking for.