# Building custom intellisense in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

I am struggling to understand how to implement JSDoc into a lib that has a build step. I have a lib that i have properly documented but when i "build" it with Babel and Webpack all the comments are put out of place and no longer picked up by VSCode. I have proven that it works prier to build. I need to have the build though because i need the code to work in IE[sigh]. 
I have found SO questions that get [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694407/adding-javascript-type-hints-for-vscode-monaco-intellisence) to what i want but not quite.

I have replicated(base structure and idea) the lib that i am working with and proven that the JSDocs [works as expected](https://codesandbox.io/s/jsdoc-example-jvxv4).
I am looked through NPM and Google looking for some examples or something similar to what i am doing and not found much. I am sure their is stuff out there i just don't know the terms to find it.

The expectation that i have is to be able to build, push up to NPM, and be able to use the library but also have intellisence helping give hints. Am i going at this the wrong way?